# Discard specific results on stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say that i have a stored procedure which returns all data from two tables: A and B.

**Table_A**

```
Id    Name
-----------------
 1    Chuck
 2    Richard
 3    Arthur
```

**Table_B**

```
Status   Nickname    IdTableA
-----------------------------
   1     cthulhu        1
   2     Poe            3
```

And the query:

```
SELECT
    a.Name, b.Status, b.Nickname
FROM 
    Table_A a
LEFT JOIN
    Table_B b ON b.IdTableA = a.Id
```

If I run the stored procedure right now, it returns all the records, even when they don't have a record in table_B (as you can see, record number 2 from table_A does not exist yet -maybe tomorrow, or in a month...-). What I need to do is discard the status number 2 (which lives on table B). The problem happens when I use something like:

```
where b.Status = 1
```

or

```
where b.Status <> 2
```

Why? Because it returns only the values with Status 1. I need only discard records with status 2, but return also the records from table_A without records on table_B.

There's a way to do that?

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show samples for your current output and your required output

Comment: At a guess, don't use `where`, add your criteria to the `on` clause: `on b.IdTableA = a.Id and b.Status <> 2`

Answer (score 1):

Does the following screenshot fulfil your requirement?

[image]

try the following:

```
declare @table_a table (id int, name varchar(100))
insert into @table_a select 1, 'Chuck'
union select 2, 'Richard'
union select 3, 'Arthur'

declare @table_b table (status int, nickname varchar(100), id_table_a int)
insert into @table_b
select 1, 'cthulhu', 1
union select 2, 'Poe', 3

select * from @table_a
select * from @table_b

select *
from @table_a a
left join @table_b b on a.id = b.id_table_a
where isnull(status,'') <> 2
```